# What is the difference between instance&class method include&extend (Ruby, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between class method and instance method.

I need to use some functions in a helper "RemoteFocusHelper" (under app/helpers/)

Then include the helper "RemoteFocusHelper" in the Worker module

But when I tried to call 'check_environment' (defined in  **RemoteFocusHelper**),

It raised ""no method error"".

Instead of using "include", I used the "extend" and works.

I wonder know if it is correct that we can only use a class method when in a class method.

Is it possible to call a instance method in a class method ?

By the way,how does the  **rake resque:work QUEUE='*'** know where to search the  **RemoteFocusHelper** I didn't give it the file path.Is the rake command will trace all files under the Rails app?

```
automation_worker.rb


    class AutomationWorker
      @queue = :automation

      def self.perform(task=false)
        include RemoteFocusHelper
        if task
          ap task
          binding.pry
          check_environment
        else
          ap "there is no task to do"      
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the context where you're executing. Pretty much every tutorial will have `include` or `extend` under the `class`:

```
class Foo
  include Thingy
end

class Bar
  extend Thingy
end
```

This will get executed at the time the class is defined: `self` is `Foo` (or `Bar`) (of type `Class`). `extend` will thus dump the module contents into `self` - which creates class methods.

When you do it inside a method definition, `self` is the instance object (of type `Foo` or `Bar`). Thus the place where the module gets dumped into changes. Now if you `extend` (the module contents), it dumps them into what is now `self` - resulting in instance methods.

EDIT: It is also worth noting that because `extend` works on any instance object, it is defined on `Object`. However, since only modules and classes are supposed to be able to include stuff, `include` is an instance method of `Module` class (and, by inheritance, `Class` as well). As a consequence of this, if you try putting `include` inside a definition of an instance method, it will fail hard, since most things (including your `AutomationWorker`) are not descended from `Module`, and thus do not have access to the `include` method.